# Sinon and Mocha: How to await for a promised to be resolved before assertion in test function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, sinon

I have a file where,

```
function fetchDevices () {
    device.findAll()
          .then(allDevices =>
             console.log("Fetched for DB")
    )
}
```

In the test file I have mocked the `device`. Now I want know/await whenever this `findAll()` returns a promise and then continue assertions in test function. I have tried many things and `setTimeout` isn't what I am looking for.

I can not stub `devices` because I'm already mocking it with another library which saves a lot of trouble of mocking or stubbing the properties.

Help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change:

```
function fetchDevices () {
    device.findAll()
          .then(allDevices =>
             console.log("Fetched for DB")
    )
}
```

to:

```
function fetchDevices () {
    return device.findAll()
          .then(allDevices =>
             console.log("Fetched for DB")
    )
}
```

and now `fetchDevices` returns a promise and you can `then` it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use await if you declare the callback function on the it( as async, something like this:

```
it('blablabla', async () => {
   await asyncFunction();
});
```

Comment: `fetchDevices` itself is not asynchronous; the method being used inside is

Comment: Can you subscribe to findAll()?, you could block the execution until the function i resolved

Comment: Do you mean spy? yes but cant block it

Comment: And device is being inyected in to this class? or where do you have declared device? I didn't mean a spy. What i'm thinking is, if you can subscribe with an Observable to the device.findAll() you can block the test with that observable.

Comment: I apologies for not being able to follow. Could you give me an example or reference/link?